# Is Excel being overloaded with my VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is some code from a function I have been working on Excel. I come from a PHP background so I am not new to development but I am quite new to Excel.

Basically the Excel file has a Sheet for each of those Case scenarios in the Select statement. Each sheet makes a call to the function with the parameter needed (1,2,3,etc)

The function pulls file names in through a directory, sorts through them and only pulls files with .docx extension. Then sorts the files by the filename to decide which files go to what sheet.

My question is:
The function works good, but after adding the different sheets in some don't function well, I'm wondering if maybe Excel can't handle this much programming logic (I could be wrong but I just don't have the experience w/Excel)...

Is there anything I can do to make my function more efficient? There could be a few hundred files for it to sort through in the future and that's not accounting for the other functions I planned to make. I could break it into separate Excel files instead of having one file with multiple sheets...but I just wanted to see what other possibilities there are first.

[image]

```
    ' Pass a variable to the function called deptSwt (Dept Switch) which will tell us which department we need to categorize data by
Function GetFileNames(deptSwt As Integer)

    ' Set folder path
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\SOP Excel Prototype"

    Const FileExt As String = "docx"

    Dim Result As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyFile As Object
    Dim MyFSO As Object
    Dim MyFolder As Object
    Dim MyFiles As Object
    Dim dept As Variant
    Dim deptCodes As Variant

    Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    Set MyFiles = MyFolder.Files

    ' Research built-in Result function in VBA
    ReDim Result(1 To MyFiles.Count)

    ' Build a switch to tell function which dept codes are selected based on deptSwt
    Select Case deptSwt

        Case 1
            deptCodes = Array("PNT", "VLG", "SAW")
        Case 2
            deptCodes = Array("CRT", "AST", "SHP", "SAW")
        Case 3
            deptCodes = Array("CRT", "STW", "CHL", "ALG", "ALW", "ALF", "RTE", "AFB", "SAW")
        Case 4
            deptCodes = Array("SCR", "THR", "WSH", "GLW", "PTR", "SAW")
        Case 5
            deptCodes = Array("PLB", "SAW")
        Case 6
            deptCodes = Array("DES")
        Case 7
            deptCodes = Array("AMS")
        Case 8
            deptCodes = Array("EST")
        Case 9
            deptCodes = Array("PCT")
        Case 10
            deptCodes = Array("PUR", "INV")
        Case 11
            deptCodes = Array("SAF")
        Case 12
            deptCodes = Array("GEN")

    End Select

    i = 1

    ' Loop through filenames and return within an array
    For Each MyFile In MyFiles
        If InStr(1, MyFile.Name, FileExt) <> 0 Then
              Dim toSplitFileName As Variant

              toSplitFileName = Split(MyFile.Name, "-")

              For Each dept In deptCodes

                If dept = toSplitFileName(3) Then
                    Result(i) = MyFile.Name

                    i = i + 1
                End If
              Next dept

        End If

    Next MyFile

    ReDim Preserve Result(1 To i - 1)

    'Return value on function end
    GetFileNames = Result

End Function
```

Comment: your question might be better fitted for code review, as it entails working code that could use (performance) improvements.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not overloading Excel (far from it).

Your function is easy to understand and doesn't fall into the trap of redimensioning the array on every iteration of the loop.

However, it's the wrong approach.

Traversing a directory of files is relatively slow. If I understand correctly, you are doing this once for every sheet in your workbook. I'm not sure whether Excel will consider your function volatile or non-volatile (in theory, it's volatile because the directory is external to Excel), but every change to a cell risks retriggering the directory search.

You should rewrite the code as a **sub** (a procedure) to traverse the directory once and populate the appropriate sheet as it finds an eligible file.

Use a button to launch the procedure. When it's debugged, you might make it launch on open, but this requires the worksheet to be trusted, so comes with a risk.

You should use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to avoid continually redrawing the screen and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` if you have any formulas which would be recalculated based on the files you find.

Comment: I understand some of what you are saying. Are you referring to a different method altogether to traverse the directory other than the one that I am using? Or are you saying just change the function to a procedure and continue with the same approach?

You understand correctly, I am doing that once for each worksheet. 

I am so unfamiliar with Excel terminology and even VBA terminology that I can easily become lost in an explanation at this point. This is my first VBA script. If you don't mind and think it is relevant, a code sample of what you mean would go a longways.

Comment: Also, if I remember from my reading, functions can return values but procedures can not, correct?

So, the procedure itself would need to populate the fields within the needed sheet without having a call to the procedure in the sheet?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, you have understood correctly. I've been working too much in delphi lately and forgot that the VBA keyword is "sub" to create a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The screenupdating and calculation are not that important here if you send the array to the sheet at once to the sheet at once within your main (if you go through a lot of sub directories... turn them off for sure). I doubt that the redim costs much overhead here depending on how often you call the function.

Two things that will speed this up if there are a lot of files. The simplest is to use With...End With syntax so the reference is not reestablished on each loop. I use While...Wend for loops because it tends to be faster. For something like this it is also totally reasonable to use DoEvents if there are a lot of files.

```
EDITED

    '-----simple filename array----'
    Dim vData as variant 
    Dim sTemp as String
    redim vdata(0 to myfiles.count - 1, 0 to 0) 
    x = 1
    with myfiles
       while x <= ubound(vdata,1)
         sTemp =  .files(x + 1).name
         'cleanup/parsing on sTemp
         vdata(x, 0) = stemp
         x = x + 1
         doevents 'optional   
       wend
    end with

    'Send To Sheet Line
    SendVariantToSheet vData, TopLeftCell`

Public Sub SendVariantToSheet(vData As Variant, rngCell As Range)
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = rngCell.Parent
    Set rngData = ws.Range(rngCell, _
        ws.Cells(rngCell.Row + UBound(vData , 1) - LBound(vData , 1), _
        rngCell.Column + UBound(vData, 2) - LBound(vData, 2)))
    rngData.value = vData 
End Sub
```

edit: another way to speed it up if there are lots of sheets is to declare the scripting.folder variable as a module level or public variable and pass it to your function as an optional parameter (Optional ByRef myFolder as Scripting.Folder); there is overhead when creating these objects.

Comment: There are 12 sheets. Is that a lot in your opinion? Also, I would say in the future there could be several hundred files in the directory it is traversing. Also, how would I go about turning off traversing sub-directories if needed?

Comment: I edited the vba snippet with what should be pretty quick and with a quick barebones procedure to send it to your sheet; just send the data and the top left cell where you want it sent. Also, unless you tell it to, this is not going to drill down to your subfolders

Comment: sTemp =  .files(x + 1).name - What does the . in .files do? Append data to the string sTemp?

Comment: Is sTemp = .files(x + 1).name, supposed to be sTemp = .MyFiles(x + 1).name? Having trouble understanding how excel know what "files" is if it hasn't been declared or defined somewhere...I'm really new to VBA and Excel :/

Comment: Whoops, you would use WITH MyFolder; sorry! I would add a reference to microsoft scripting runtime so you can see the intellisense. Saw your other post, this should fix it; for each is the simplest to write and read, not always the fastest. The 0 to 0 tells it that it is a 2 dimensional array so it can just be sent to the sheet cells quickly (you can start with 1 in vba arrays and the write proc will work; i never do )  The reason for stemp is only because it is lighter to store the file name if you are doing anything with it rather than referencing the file.name property several times.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the info. I wish I could figure out how to post code in these comments (code that is formatted). I've posted the example here - https://pastebin.com/RimGdW8L (since I can't seem to figure out how to format code in comments). Anyhow, the syntax is really holding me up coming from a PHP background. It seems you are trying to store file names in an array or string for later analysis, rather than call to function in sheets repeatedly. How can I easily turn that into a 2d array without for loops. Array(sheet id)(dept code) would be the structure.

Comment: Spent a large portion of my day reading several books, researching on the internet, eventually just had to move on to something else to try to relieve the mental block. Have a decent road trip tomorrow, hoping to come at it with a fresh perspective in the morning (but who knows maybe tonight)

Comment: Just a thought... maybe you could avoid the need to loop through these files by creating a data connection to the folder to create a table which lists the files. You can add a cell to the right of the table to hold your dept code. This link explains it (you just stop at the part that goes into importing that data)
https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/power-query-get-files-from-a-folder